# jquery selector for future element if visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

One of my ajax popup is loading too late.so my condition of jquery to check visibility is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('#emailCart').is(':visible')){
        alert('yes');
        let shouldFire = true;
        $("input, select").click(function(){
         if(shouldFire) {
            alert('sent');
            sendGAEvent('Email', 'click','Email Cart');
            shouldFire = false;
           }
        });
    };
});
```

seems "is(':visible')" only checks for dom loaded elements.How can i apply this conditions to future elements also.

Email cart image

[image: Email cart image]

When clicking on this Email cart button many textboxes appear on clicking any one of those my code should work. I am using a tool tempormonkey by which i inject my code to websites.But my code is not working when i inject using tempormonkey but instead works with console.

Comment: Please share whole function with `.ready`. i think you defined you function inside `.ready` method.

Comment: You can't, nobody knows the future, not even jQuery. If you're populating something with AJAX, do everything related to the new elements in the AJAX `success` handler.

Comment: @DevangHingu yes its inside .ready.Updating.

Comment: @pravinmishra Can you update question with full code.

Comment: @Teemu i don't have access to the main code. And methods like .on() works for future elements.

Comment: `on` doesn't work for future elements, with `on` you set a listener to an exisiting element, and when the event fires, `on` takes the advantage of the event bubbling system, it's not magic.

Comment: @DeepakDixit updated please check.

Comment: @Teemu thankyou i didn't new that.Sorry i am new to jquery.BTW plesae help.

Comment: @pravinmishra just move your function outside of `.ready` method. it will surely works

Comment: @DevangHingu trying

Comment: @DevangHingu not working

Comment: Is this `#emailCart` the pop-up "loaded too late"? If it is, you could put up a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track occurring of the pop-up.

Comment: You're doing this backwards. You should add the event handler to the elements unconditionally. The event handler function can check whether the element is visible, and return if not.

Comment: And you can use event delegation if the input elements are loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar  i am not getting it.I am new to jquery.Please provide answer.

Comment: @pravinmishra You are saying that its related to ajax popup but your code does not contain any AJAX code. Please update it also.

Comment: @DeepakDixit i don't have access to complete code i am using addon extension tempormonkey to add my code to a website.

Comment: You didn't consider Tampermonkey being an important information to add to your question ..?

Comment: @Teemu sorry sir

Comment: The trick is to register the EventHandler with $(document).on('click', '.yourclass', functionName)

If you do so, you are registering that event dynamically that is able to trigger the event after the Target Element is created after loaded. you know what I mean? If not google for  $(document).on() method.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around: check the visibility in the handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input, select").click(function() {
    if ($('#emailCart').is(':visible')) {
      alert('sent');
      sendGAEvent('Email', 'click', 'Email Cart');
    }
  });
});
```

If the `input` and `select` elements are loaded dynamically, use event delegation as described in [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). But that doesn't change the logic of how to check for visibility of the cart.

Comment: i am applying this to this website using tempormonkey tool.https://qa1.thermofisher.in/chemicals/shop/cart/

Comment: See it where? Please update the question with the HTML.

Comment: If the inputs are in the popup, you don't even need the conditional. If it's not visible, they can't click on it.

Comment: @Barmer i have updated the question. Thier are multiple inputs in the website i want this condition only for some inputs only when a particular id apperas.

Comment: please help i am stucked.

Comment: I asked you to post your HTML. Also, do you want the click handler just for certain inputs? Then you need a more specific selector, like `$("#emailCart").find("input, select")`

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to write such code which will execute in future but we can monitor that on click of document because you are saying that on click of **Email Cart** button you want to execute it.

I hope it will resolve your issue, try it:-

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('#emailCart').is(':visible')) return;

    alert('yes');
    let shouldFire = true;

    $("input, select").click(() => {
        if (!shouldFire) return;
        alert('sent');
        sendGAEvent('Email', 'click', 'Email Cart');
        shouldFire = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Dit not working.I noticed its preloaded and just the display property of css is changing to  none when not clicked on email cart button.

Comment: What do you mean by preloaded?